# MS-Access 2007 query with conditions on two fields

Tags: ms-access

I have a dataset with unique records that includes 2 fields: RName and RVer.  A subset looks like this:

```
RName, RVer
Joe,   2 
Joe,   3
Joe,   4
Joe,   5
Bill,  1
Bill,  5
```

I want to query on a Version number "MaxVer", returning each instance of a RName whose RVer is the greatest one, less than or equal to MaxVer.  If a RName has no RVer less than or equal to MaxVer, then that RName is not returned at all.

Here are examples of the query and the desired return:

```
MaxVer  ---> Returns --->   Dataset Returned
1                           Bill,1
2                           Bill,1  and  Joe,2
3                           Bill,1  and  Joe,3
4                           Bill,1  and  Joe,4
5                           Bill,5  and  Joe,5
6                           Bill,5  and  Joe,5
```

This is the closest I've come so far, but it's not very close at all:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MainTbl.RName, MainTbl.RVer
FROM MainTbl
WHERE MainTbl.RVer <= MaxVer;
```

Using MaxVer=4 as a test case, this SQL query returns 4 records:

```
Bill,1   and   Joe,2   and   Joe,3   and Joe,4
```

If someone would help me out here, I'd surely appreciate it!

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT MainTbl.RName, Max(MainTbl.RVer) AS MaxRVer
FROM MainTbl
WHERE (MainTbl.RVer)<=[MaxVer]
GROUP BY MainTbl.RName;
```

You can test it [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ba4b/1/0).

Comment: Superb!  Exactly the results I needed, thank you so much!  Also, very kind of you to lay it out on SQLFiddle.com; I did not know the site existed. Dave

Comment: @Dave2.71828, You are Welcome.